# redundant distributed filesystems for small number of nodes

Tags: filesystems, grid, distributed-system

I need to keep a filesystem shared between two nodes in different locations, in a way fully redundant, so that programs running in both nodes should see the whole filesystem.

The situation is that a datafile could be stored in any of the nodes, then a program running in the other could have been notified by a third party about the existence of the file, and it expects it to exist. A rsync mirroring has too much latency, even if accelerated with house-made tricks (inotify, for one). Definitely we need a shared filesystem.

Redundandy is wanted in order to be sure that we can keep going with a single node if the other datacenter becomes unreacheable.

Having only two or three nodes to share the files, probably lustre or HDFS is overkill, but it could be considered, Ceph seems too young, XtreemFS has difficulties, and DRBD sounds nice (and small) but I am afraid it could have problems to jump over high network latencies, between sites.

Am I missing some posibility? Is someone actually having this setup, sharing a filesystem  across two data centers?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend excellent [LizardFS](http://lizardfs.com/) and [GfarmFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gfarm_file_system).

*Ceph* is too complex hence very unreliable and fragile; it is mostly used for block storage and the Ceph file system is very slow. I recommend to avoid Ceph due to its complexity and gross disregard to data integrity.
*XtreemFS* is slow (probably because of Java); its build system is messy; it have problems with data integrity and depends on non-free/unmaintained .JARs.

[MARS](https://schoebel.github.io/mars/) could be a better alternative to DRBD but as I recall *MARS* needs modified kernel and its DKMS version is yet to be released.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Mirror File System (MFS) developed by Twin Peaks Software can meet
your need?
http://TwinPeakSoft.com/